# When should I return the current instance as opposed to void?

Tags: java, return-value, return-type

Consider this scenario:

```
public void setInt(int i){
    this.i = i;
}
```

versus:

```
public MyClass setInt(int i) {
    this.i = i;
    return this;
}
```

Consider if you want to print the internal integer.  If we use `void` as a return value to `setInt`, we use this code:

```
MyClass m = new Class();
m.setInt(10);
System.out.println(m.getInt());
```

If we use `MyClass` as the return value to `setInt`, we use this code:

```
System.out.println(new MyClass().setInt(10).getInt());
```

To me, the second approach seems cleaner and tidier, but I've still got a question about these approaches.

- In what circumstances would the first approach (using `void`) be OK to use?
- In what circumstances would the second approach be OK to use?

Comment: You can do it both ways returning void

Comment: @FranMontero i know i can do it both ways, but which is better to use than other one?

Comment: If caller does not need the `MyClass` object, returning it is a no-sense

Comment: What if your method doesn't change state but just stores something to database or displays on the screen. What are you going to return?

Comment: @FranMontero once you create a class to be used other places then we don't know if returning it is useful or not

Comment: Not all methods are intended for chained calls.  The `void` return type can make it easier to add a return type later. If you're overriding a superclass `void` method, you have to match the existing signature. Etc. ...

Comment: Hey, guys?  This pattern is common enough in Java that it has its own name - [builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).  Why should we close this question?  There's a clear answer here.

Comment: @Makoto well, others think otherwise. I really want to adapt to such pattern, but before I do I want to figure out advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: @Makoto the fact that the builder pattern exists and is useful doesn't imply that `void` methods should never be used and that there is always something sensible to return from every method. The question wasn't if chaining was useful, it was whether `void` is not useful. You have edited it into a different question - which you should *not* have done. And that question is still rather opinion-based because there will always be borderline situations to argue about.

Comment: @Makoto thx alot for providing the link, I can read about it now I know there is a name for it

Comment: @RealSkeptic mate, I don't see the question has change into another question, It is certainly neater with less confusion but still asking the same question that I had in mind

Comment: @Makoto The pattern itself is called [fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface), one (but not the only) usage of which is builders.

Comment: @nafas If so, then the edit is fine. Still an opinion-based question, though.

Comment: @RealSkeptic being opinion-based is also opinion-based pal , but its ok I got what I needed. thx  :)

Comment: @nafas Where you objectively can't use this pattern is before Java 5, where subclasses couldn't override methods and define a narrower return type.